# How to get correlation matrix as upper half of the matrix with splom using plotly in R

Tags: r, plotly, r-plotly

I used splom for pair plots. I would like to draw pair plots with correlation values like provided in R base pair plots. I didn't find the correlation display with pair plots using splom with plotly in R. I go though below links for plotting the pair plots in that they didn't mention pair plot with correlation values.

[link](https://plotly.com/r/splom/) that I followed for drawing pair plots.

Desired visualizations with spolm using plotly:

[image]

Is that desired visualization possible with splom using plotly in R?

Comment: How do you get your base plot ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added a base example too, to make this answer more informative.
One of the solution will be to use `GGally::ggpairs` and `plotly::ggplotly` functions. Of course the plot returned by `plotly::ggplotly` will be interactive.

```r
# Base plot

panel.cor <- function(x, y) {
  usr <- par("usr")
  on.exit(par(usr))
  par(usr = c(0, 1, 0, 1))
  r <- round(cor(x, y), digits = 2)
  # possible to edit the size
  text(0.5, 0.5, r)
}

pairs(iris[, 1:4],
  upper.panel = panel.cor
)
```

[image]

```r
## GGally solution - plotly
## assume GGally and plotly are installed

pm <- GGally::ggpairs(iris[, 1:4])
#> Registered S3 method overwritten by 'GGally':
#>   method from   
#>   +.gg   ggplot2
class(pm)
#> [1] "gg"       "ggmatrix"
plotly::ggplotly(pm)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-07-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>